# Can I query this array in php to produce a result or should it have been done in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

In the array below I have a collection of data from a results table.  This data shows which player has been defeated the most by the user, whether they were Player 1 or Player 2.

```
[[{"player2_id":"31","player2_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player2_id":"31","player2_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player2_id":"31","player2_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player2_id":"31","player2_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player2_id":"31","player2_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player1_id":"31","player1_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player1_id":"31","player1_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player1_id":"31","player1_name":"Jamie Charles"},
{"player1_id":"32","player1_name":"steve downs"},   
{"player1_id":"31","player1_name":"Jamie Charles"}]]
```

As you can see `playerX_id:31` appears 9 times, 5 as player2_id, and 4 as player1_id.

(to get this table I had to run 2x queries and add both results to the table - one for when the user in question was player 1, and one for when the user was player 2)

Essentially all I want to do from this data is see what `playerX_id` appears the most and take the name that corresponds.

So my desired output would be `Jamie Charles`

Can I do this from this array or is that something that should have been done at MySQL level?

This is my table:

`+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| results_id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| community_id   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_team   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_goals  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_result | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_goals  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_result | varchar(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_name   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_team   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player1_pts    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| player2_pts    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date           | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+`

And this is my MySQL query:

```
public function getTotalMostWinsAgainst($playerId){

    $returnValue = array();
    $sql = "SELECT player2_id, player2_name FROM `results` WHERE player1_id = '".$playerId."' AND player1_result = 'W'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   if(!empty($row)){
      $returnValue[] = $row;
   }
}
}

$sql = "SELECT player1_id, player1_name FROM `results` WHERE player2_id = '".$playerId."' AND player2_result = 'W'";

$result = $this->conn->query($sql);
    if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){
while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 if(!empty($row)){
    $returnValue[] = $row;
   }
}
}
    return $returnValue;
} 


}
```

Comment: Can you also show the database structure or the queries? Seems that you can do that with one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select member, count(*) Total
from 
(
select player2_name as member
from results
WHERE player1_id = 2 AND player1_result = 'W'
union all
select player1_name
from results
WHERE player2_id = 2 AND player2_result = 'W'

) AS T

group by member
order by Total desc
Limit 1
```

This should give you the first result order by the name that appears most as player 2 when player 1 has won and vice-versa